# Android SQLite Database Online

Tags: android, sqlite

I create my database using Firefox SQL Manager.

I have a DatabaseHelper class which copies my sqlite database from the assets folder to the databases of the package.

My android activities read the database and projects the results onto TextViews and ListViews.

I need to put this database online, I read a couple of blogs but non mention how I must go about in my case since I run rawQueries from the Database class so in simply terms, I do not want to modify anything on the DatabaseHelper class except for database PATH? I do not write I only read and if I do need to write/update I use GUI SQL Manager on FireFox. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to push the database online, the way I would handle that would be to build a middle layer of web services and use `DefaultHttpClient` code to grab data from the DB. I'm not aware of any way to access a remote SQLite DB (but that doesn't mean it's not possible, just that I'm ignorant!)

Comment: I read that sqlite can be accessed as a file so I do not need any webservice middleware, can't I just use Uri (url to sqlite on server) or something like that?

Comment: As I said, I don't know if that's possible. I would use web service's!

Answer (score 0):

Why u want to access a external database i.e in assets folder?just place the database in the data/data/"projectname"/databases folder of your emulator and u can access it directly.

Comment: That is what I am doing now but I want to have the database on a remote server (online) not in assets, I do not want to have to update the app every time changes are made to the database